# Character wiping fog off a mirror using dynamic paint

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, materials, shaders, dynamic-paint

I've been making a scene where a character wipes fog and water droplets off a mirror to reflect themselves. I made a dynamic paint sequence using the character as the brush, but i cant work out the way to make the material so the paint brush paints a mirror texture on and leaves the fog texture. I can only get it to either paint the fog on or leave a black background. [image]
 How can i make the brush work as a layer on top of the original water droplets texture?
[image]

Comment: we would need to see the Nodes, but I would guess you just need to use your Dynamic Paint image sequence as the Factor to a Mix Node that controls the Mirror vs Fog

Comment: Hi rob, thats what i was using there originally, but it made the wrong bits foggy and clean. I got it to work somehow by putting a logorithm math node in the mix and playing around. Not sure why it worked but my nodes are a bit of a mess after much trial and error

Comment: Post an answer with a screen shot of your Nodes to help others.

Comment: I used a dynamic paint in image mode with a wetmap and put that through a colour ramp and a logorithm set at 0.9. If anybody knows why that worked I'd love to know. I will make some screenshots now

Answer (score 2):

So using a LOG math node at 0.9 with a colour ramp into the factor did the trick. If anyone knows exactly why I'd love to know. [image]

[image]